# How to redirect to another page on the server when hyperlink is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a homepage titled index.php located in the public_html folder on the server I'm using to host my webpage. I also have a folder named Assignment1 inside the public_html, and inside that folder is an .html file, a .css file, and a .js file.

On my homepage (index.php) I have an anchor tag and what I want to do is when the user clicks on the anchor, it redirects the page to the .html file in the Assignment1 folder so it displays my entire Assignment 1.

What I'm having trouble with is I have no idea how to do this. How do i reference that .html file in the Assignment1 folder and make it so when you click on it that's what it redirects to? I have tried putting the absolute path in the href of the anchor tag but that obviously didn't work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why not `<a href="assignment1.html">Assignment1</a>`?

Comment: absolute web path should work fine. Show sample code you tried  for `href`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="Assignment1/assignment.html">Assignment1</a>
```